# My IF statement on both IntelliJ and Visual Studio code no longer works

Tags: java

So I recently started with java over IntelliJ but am using it on Visual Studio Code now because i read that i should use it when I was looking for a fix to my problem.
Im making a Script right now requiring the IF statement, a few days ago the IF statement worked perfectly on all Scripts i had made before but now it doesnt work at all anymore just getting skipped over, ive been on google searching for the problem for the past 3h now and cant find anything, here i see theres a lot of talented programmers with way more expirience than me so im handing this to you because im at my end.(the scripts is supposed to then open something in the explorer which is why those imports are there)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        String Test;
        Test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "example question?");
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "currently unused do to IF not working");


        if (Test.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) { 
            System.out.println(Test + "success");
        }

            //System.exit(0); IF still doesnt work so i put this here in comments
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,   "(" + Test + ")fail");
    }
}`
```

another code that also doesnt work anymore:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BOX {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Eingabe;
        Eingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Wie heißt du?");
        if (Eingabe == null) {
            Runtime.getRuntime(). halt(0);
        }


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guten Tag " + Eingabe);
        String Eingabee;
        Eingabee = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Wie alt bist du?");
        if (Eingabee == null) System.exit(0);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Du bist " + Eingabe + " und " + Eingabee + " Jahre alt.");


    }
}
```

I really hope that you guys can help me on this

Ive changed the `if (Test == "a")` to `if (Test.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))`, also before it checked for "a" i was checking for null. i added {} to the IF statement, i tried adding an else altho i later read that having it did break someones script so i removed it without success. i tried replacing System.exit(0) with Runtime.getRuntime(). halt(), which also doesnt work because it doesnt even get to that since IF always it not true. Switching from IntelliJ to Visual Studio Code. Checking if the script even got to the IF statement. And like 500 different forums and sites with similar problems.

Comment: IMHO this works as expected: if I enter "A" into the input dialog it prints "Asuccess" to the console and then shows  message dialog with "(A)fail". If I enter "B" into the input dialog it only shows the message dialog with "(B)fail". What other outcome did you expect?

Comment: for me it never gets to success, i always get the second outcome

Comment: About your second example, `showInputDialog` will never return `null`, so your `if`'s condition will never be true. If you want to check whether the input is empty you'll have to do something like `if("".equals(Eingabee))`

Comment: You should always get the second outcome. It should print the output AND show the dialog. Can you include a `System.out.println("input is:" + Test + ".");` Then copy and paste that output?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca how did it work before then, it returned null and closed the programm, now it no longer does, i havent update- wait right i did update my pc just yesterday and since then i didnt test those scripts bc they worked after i was done with them but now they dont work anymore

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca did you try cancelling the input dialog? I get null.

Comment: for me it still returns null but doesnt close anymore

Comment: exactly that but it just doesnt close anymore, it returns null but doesnt close after

Comment: What doesn't close?  The input dialog?  Because the dialog closes for me when I Cancel it.  And when I click OK, it closes and I get a non-null String.  (I am compiling and running your 2nd example from the command line.)

Comment: the programm, like if you leave the box empty the script should be stopped and not continue and thats what it did but now for some reason it doesnt stop if i leave the box empty anymore, it the same problem for the first script i sent, because it was also set to close upon null or "no"

Comment: The script will only stop if you cancel the dialog. If you click OK with empty input then you get an empty string and it doesn't exit the program.

Comment: The application exits for me.  Perhaps you are using Windows ... with its weird habit of creating a new console to run your Java application ...

Comment: @matt when i finished the script and ran it, it closed if i left the textbox empty returning with exit code 0 just like it should, now it doesnt close but still at the end return exit code 0
StephenC i would assume at this point its just windows after the new update.

Comment: I have no idea whether this is caused by a Windows update.  I don't use Windows.

Answer (score 1):

OK ... so the program as written is going to do the following:

1. Ask the user for input in a dialog.
2. Test if it is "a" or "A", and print "success" if it is.
3. **Unconditionally** show "fail" in a message dialog.

So it will **always** display the "fail" dialog.  Even if it also prints "success" on the console.

I think you *meant* to write this:

```
    if (Test.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) { 
        System.out.println(Test + "success");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,   "(" + Test + ")fail");
    }
```

Comment: i had to cut a lot of code and that with the fail is me just checking to see if it even gets to that point and if it did, it tells me that ive failed again, you can ignore/delete that part of the code

Comment: Mate ... if you want people to help you with code, you need to post precisely the code you want help with.  If you post different code, you are wasting everyone's time.  Including your own.   Edit the question to contain **precisely** the code you want us to help you with.

Comment: initially, the question could be answered with yes, no ect but for testing i rewrote because it didnt work, so the actual intend is for the programm to close it null or no is answered yet it never did, so to check if the IF statement worked i rewrote it and it still doesnt work for me

Comment: See my previous comment.   We can't explain code we cannot see.

Comment: the thing is, the IF statement doesnt work at all anymore, like on all the other scripts it just stopped working because if the input box was left empty it should be null and then the IF should check for null and if it is it should exit but it doesnt anymore, so i replayed the exit with a text box which didnt work either

Comment: See my previous comment. We can't explain code we cannot see.

Comment: like i said, IF statement doesnt work anywhere anymore not on different scripts or programms

Comment: Like I said, we can't explain it without seeing the actual code.  I'm sure there >is< an explanation ... but ... I'm not going to say what I have said before a 4th time.

Comment: @gost `if` statements don't stop working just because. There's something wrong with your code, but as Stephen is trying to tell you we can't know what's wrong if we don't see the *actual* code that's not working. Not a description of said code. Not a piece of code you think is similar but doesn't display the same problem. The *actual* code.

Comment: if i could share the actual code i would but i am unable to, this code i shared doesnt work even with the improvements, thats the problem.

Comment: Well in that case, we cannot help you.  Sorry.

Comment: i can share you the other script that doesnt work, its in german tho:

Comment: and its too many characters aswell, uhhhhh how do i do this?

Comment: Please read about how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  It explains what we need, and why.

Comment: @gost [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74885950/edit) your question and put that code after what's already there, pointing out that it's another piece of code that it's giving the same problem.

Comment: done, i added another code on which the IF statement previously worked but no longer work(havent changed that code since creation and it worked perfectly fine, exiting with me leaving the box empty